# How to update existing AWS profile Value?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created profile on my new laptop.

```
aws configure list
```

shows

```
     Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************FFAQ shared-credentials-file    
secret_key     ****************0lv7 shared-credentials-file    
    region                <not set>             None    None
```

How to set Value to borisjohnson?
I tried

```
aws update-profile --profile-name borisjohnson
```

but that does not work.

It seems that Terraform does not recognize it as default

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = var.region
}
```

Comment: You mean the profile name?

Comment: @Paolo Yes,exactly the profile name.

Comment: So just to be clear, you want to rename the `default` profile to another name?

Comment: @Paolo Yes,I have problem with Terraform

Comment: Which machine are you using?

Comment: @DevangSanghani Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

Comment: You can edit the files directly: `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`